# Resources as nodes in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

Is there any way to use a XAML resource as a node instead of an attribute? Something like this?

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Button x:Key="TestButton" x:Shared="False" Content="..." />
</Window.Resources>

<my:ButtonBar x:Name="ButtonBar1">
    <my:ButtonBar.Buttons>
        {StaticResource TestButton}
    </my:ButtonBar.Buttons>
<my:ButtonBar>

<my:ButtonBar x:Name="ButtonBar2">
    <my:ButtonBar.Buttons>
        {StaticResource TestButton}
    </my:ButtonBar.Buttons>
<my:ButtonBar>
```

Obviously this is just an example and obviously this won't work.

But how could I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
<my:ButtonBar x:Name="ButtonBar1">
    <my:ButtonBar.Buttons>
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="TestButton" />
    </my:ButtonBar.Buttons>
<my:ButtonBar>
```